# Does shifting gears at 10000 rpm damage my car?

Tags: engine, rpm

If you drive a high power gasoline sports or a muscle car with a manual transmission, will it do any damage if I shift gears at 10000 rpm?

Comment: Do you mean 1,000RPM (one thousand) not 10,000RPM (ten thousand)? Even if we're talking racing cars, 10,000RPM is usually not achievable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Assuming the redline is 10000RPM+. E.g. a slightly modified Mazda RX8 should have a 10k+RPM redline.

Comment: Might have to make use of a quickshift to cut the engine momentarily or lift off the accelerator so you don't throw it over the red line.  Certainly most sports motorbikes rev that high but not aware of many road cars that redline above 10,000rpm

Comment: The RX8 is one of few that can be reasonably cheaply modified to rev that high. It revs to 9000 standard (it's a rotary after all).

Comment: Honda S2000 also has crazy high revs. 9k is the redline for s2000.